# целое словосочетание как прилагательное

Tags: части-речи

может ли целое словосочетание, к примеру такое как "широко распространенный", быть прилагательным?

То есть, "широко распространенный" часть речи - прилагательное.

Answer (score 1):

‟Широко распространенный” — это словосочетание с видом связи примыкание, которое состоит из двух слов: ‟широко” — наречие меры, и ‟распространенный” — причастие.
...Я не очень понял вопрос на самом деле... Может ли быть это сочетание прилагательным? Нет, потому что это сочетание двух слов, которые являются разными частями речи.